# Capybaraのfindメソッドで中身が空の要素をヒットさせたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

```
<div id="hoge"></div>
```

上記のような中身が空の要素をCapybaraのfindで見つけたいのですが、ヒットしません。

```
find("#hoge") # => Capybara::ElementNotFound Exception: Unable to find visible css "#hoge"
```

ヒットさせる方法はありますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find('#hoge', visible: :all)
```

とするとヒット出来ます。Capybaraはデフォルトではvisibleでないエレメントはfindしません。